# Select middle part of string MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Good day

I have problem i can not fix query to select middle pat of string.

I have table with 1000+ rows and strings like :

```
x0gdfg992|x05gjy652|t0kk2:-
```

I need select part: `x05gjy652`

Thank you for opinions

I can not change input data.

Comment: Fixed positions, or variable?

Comment: Check this link - https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/969662/How-to-get-a-substring-between-two-characters

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @String nvarchar(100)
SET @String='x0gdfg992|x05gjy652|t0kk2'

SELECT SUBSTRING(String,0,CHARINDEX('|',String)) AS RequiredPart    
FROM
(
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('|',@String)+1,LEN(@String)) AS String
)dt
```

Result,Demo:http://rextester.com/OSSUS74768

```
RequiredPart
--------------
x05gjy652
```

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```
declare @s nvarchar(100)

SET @s = N'x0gdfg992|x05gjy652|t0kk2:-'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('|',@s)+1, (CHARINDEX('|',@s,(CHARINDEX('|',@s)+1)))-CHARINDEX('|',@s) -1 )
```

1. `CHARINDEX('|',@s)+1` ... finds the position of the first `|`
2. `(CHARINDEX('|',@s,(CHARINDEX('|',@s)+1)))-CHARINDEX('|',@s) -1` ... Calculates the string length need for the string between first `|` and second `|`.

In detail the second item which can be confusing:

1. `(CHARINDEX('|',@s,(CHARINDEX('|',@s)+1)))` ... searching for `|` after the first `|` (starting point is `(CHARINDEX('|',@s)+1)`)
2. `CHARINDEX('|',@s)` ... position of the first `|`
3. `-1` ... is to exclude the last `|`.

Answer (score 0):

Peronsally, I would use a String Splitter which gives Ordinal Position; for example Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

This then becomes trivial:

```
SELECT DS.Item
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY DelimitedSplit8K(YT.YourString, '|') DS
WHERE DS.ItemNumber = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is via a little XML

**Example**

```
Select NewValue=cast('<x>' + replace(SomeCol,'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
 From YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
x05gjy652
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(200)='x0gdfg992|x05gjy652|t0kk2',
        @B VARCHAR(500)

SELECT @B=SUBSTRING(@A,CHARINDEX('|',@A,1)+1,LEN(@A))
SELECT 
SUBSTRING((SUBSTRING(@A,CHARINDEX('|',@A,1)+1,LEN(@A))),1,CHARINDEX('|', 
(SUBSTRING(@A,CHARINDEX('|',@A,1)+1,LEN(@A))),1)-1)
```